# How to run node.js project with yarn on graalvm?

Tags: javascript, yarnpkg, graalvm, polyglot

Which steps should I take to migrate my current yarn project to run on graalvm?

This [doc](https://www.graalvm.org/docs/examples/polyglot-javascript-java-r/) describes a simple start but does not mention `yarn`, running tests, etc.

Comment: As described here https://www.graalvm.org/docs/ GraalVM comes with a "Node.js runtime with the GraalVM JavaScript interpreter enabled as the JavaScript engine.". So then install that and run yarn in it. There should be no other "setup" or "migration" needed.